# Null to empty values

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to use a data mapper mediator to trasform a complex JSON, I need to change names of fields and convert null strings to empty strings.

> Input:

```
{
  "field1" : "value 1",
  "field2" : "value 2",
  "field3" : null,
  "field4" : null,
  [...]
}
```

> Output:

```
{
  "One" : "value 1",
  "Two" : "value 2",
  "Three" : "",
  "Four" : "",
  [...]
}
```

I've implemented my own *nullToEmpty* function and used in a *CustomFunction Operation* , but I cannot reuse it, if I do it is duplicated for any field that use it.

Is there a better way to act this trasformation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no way to reuse custom functions with the DataMapper. Unfortunately, you will have to duplicate the code.